# Add new instance of object to list with new values without overwriting old ones using C#

Tags: c#, xml, list

So I've been Googling around for a while and have searched through a number of StackOverflow posts and I must be missing something. I'm doing some XML parsing using C# and I have a series of classes as shown below. In short, the class "Grade" contains a list of of the class "Classroom" and Classroom has a list of "Students" and a list of Teachers.

```
class Individual
{
   public string ID;
   public string fName;
   public string lName;
   public string gradeID;
}

class Classroom
{
   public string classID;
   public string className;
   public string classGrade;
   public int numTeachers;
   public List<Individual> Students;
   public List<Individual> Teachers;
}
class Grade
{
   public List<Classroom> Classrooms;
   public string classGrade;
}
```

Essentially, in my program I sift through the XML file and collect a list of students and teachers and add them to my classroom WITHOUT any of them being overwritten. This is because, in a loop, I create a new instance of the class each time the XML node's name is equivalent to "student" or "teacher" because a new node of that type indicates a new individual. You can see that done here:

```
// node is a student
else if (xmlReader.Name == "student")
{
    // create new student object
    Individual tempStudent = new Individual();
    tempStudent.ID = xmlReader.GetAttribute("id");
    tempStudent.fName = xmlReader.GetAttribute("first_name");
    tempStudent.lName = xmlReader.GetAttribute("last_name");
    tempStudent.gradeID = tempClassroom.classID;
    // add student object to classroom list of students
    tempClassroom.Students.Add(tempStudent); // classroom class is used inside student and teacher if statements
}
```

However, I cannot do the same for classroom or grade, since, as you can see above, student and teacher are both dependent on the classroom class for storage purposes. As a result, I cannot figure out how to create a NEW classroom object so that when I do grade.Add(classroom) I can start modifying classroom WITHOUT modifying the already existing nodes within grade. And again, I'd rather not have to write a deep copy function for every time a new classroom is present because that will be incredibly slow.

Edit: sample XML file here:
https://pastebin.com/XzSxgLdb

This code seems to have fixed my problems. When the xmlNodeType was an EndElement I checked the name and then created a new classroom or new grade as necessary. I don't have anymore overwrites so that seems to have cleared things up.

I feel like C# should know that when you add an object to a container that you want that object saved and so C# should create a new reference for a new object. But I guess that isn't the case. Explicitly declaring a new object every time you need one is required.

```
case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
    if (xmlReader.Name == "classroom")
    {
        // at end of classroom element so add classroom to list
        tempClassroom.numTeachers = teacherCounter;
        grade.Classrooms.Add(tempClassroom);
        if (teacherCounter > highestNumberOfTeachers)   // collect the highest number of recorded teachers in a classroom
            highestNumberOfTeachers = teacherCounter;
        teacherCounter = 0;
        tempClassroom = new Classroom();
    }
    if (xmlReader.Name == "grade")
    {
        // at end of grade element so prepare for next grade level
        Grades.Add(grade);
        grade = new Grade();
    }
```

Comment: Adding a sample piece of XML might go a long way ;).

Comment: So you basically want a new classRoom with the students and the teachers from the old one? Or why shouldn't you make a new one, if the properties are new ones as well?

Comment: Difficult to understand the question! Need more clearlity with some more code and xml structure!